# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException when running Flutter app with sqflite

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I'm trying to use SQLite database using the `sqflite` plugin. Running the app below results in `Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException` error.
Here's my code:

`main.dart`:

```
...
late final Database database;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  database = await openDatabase(
    join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'mydb.db'),
    version: 1,
    onCreate: (db, version) {
      return db.execute('CREATE TABLE config(key TEXT PRIMARY KEY, value TEXT)');
    },
  );

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      title: 'MyApp',
      initialRoute: '/',
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) => onGenerateRoute(settings),
      onUnknownRoute: pageNotImplementedRoute,
    );
  }
}

Route? onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
  ...
}

Route pageNotImplementedRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
  return MaterialPageRoute<void>(...);
}
```

Here's the output from the run:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
?  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56398/fJzrmThsqQA=/ws
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86 64...
E/flutter ( 6173): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)
E/flutter ( 6173): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:154:7)
E/flutter ( 6173): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6173): #1      wrapDatabaseException (package:sqflite/src/exception_impl.dart:7:20)
E/flutter ( 6173): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6173): #2      SqfliteDatabaseFactoryMixin.getDatabasesPath (package:sqflite_common/src/factory_mixin.dart:152:20)
E/flutter ( 6173): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6173): #3      main (package:mymedica/main.dart:76:10)
E/flutter ( 6173): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6173):
```

Anyone has any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Error when using sqflite package. just had to stop and run the app, issue got solved

Comment: `Simply Run these commands.. 

either--

Flutter clean

or

Invalidate Caches/Restart`

Comment: Already done multiple times. Still same results.

Comment: can you share step

Comment: In terminal: `flutter clean`. Then `flutter pub get`. Also in Android Studio: `File - Invalidate caches / Restart...`

Comment: Using `sqflite` is my last ditch effort to not use `shared_preferences` which also keeps giving `Missing plugin exception` which has caused me headache for the past one week.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239767/discussion-between-anmol-mishra-and-roslan-amir).

Answer (score 0):

This error is just because the SQFLite dependency not get it's package. you should follow this steps. It's Work for me...

1. `flutter clean`
2. File > Invalide caches & Restart
3. `flutter pub get`

And you will get your desired outcome.!

Comment: Like I mentioned in the comment above, I did that multiple times with same results.